# Android Fragment inflate error with Camera

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera, inflate-exception

**context**

I have a fragment with button to attach camera image. When I open the fragment and tap on attach image then I keep the camera opened. When I open the native mobile camera app and take a photo then I return back to my app (which have the camera opened)

**error**

I take a photo and tap on done or even press back button this exception appears to me

```
"InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class fragment"
```

Any suggestions ?
Thanks.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: This is the xml which has the exception

`<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.a.b.c.EFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_e"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />`

and I put this line to keep activity state
`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`